# Understanding David Deutsch's second equation from his paper The Structure of the Multiverse

Tags: functions, inverse-function, multisets

### Background

David Deutsch's paper [The Structure of the Multiverse](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0104033.pdf) is concerned with the theory of quantum information and quantum computation, but the first few pages contain a purely mathematical prelude. While reading this prelude, I failed to understand one equation in particular.

He begins by considering a classical reversible computational network N with bits $B_1$,...,$B_N$. The functions $b_1(t)$,...,$b_N(t)$ represent the boolean value of the bits just after the $t$'th computational step. We can refer to this sequence of bits as the number $b(t)=2^{N-1}b_N(t) + ... + 2b_2(t) + b_1(t)$.

During each computational step, the values of the bits in the network change according to this equation:

$$
b(t+1)=f_t(b(t))
\tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$

Where each $f_t$ is some invertible function from $Z_{2^N}$ to itself, which characterizes the action of all the gates through which the bits pass during the $(t+1)$'th computational step.

All good so far.

On page 5, he introduces the notion of a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), which he describes as an NM-bit network that is a multiset of M networks, each with N bits. He further introduces the notion of multiplicity, which is denoted as $\mu_b(t)$ and defined as the number of sub-networks that are in the state $b \in Z_{2^N}$ at time $t$.

Again, all good so far. But he loses me here, when he introduces the equation of motion for how the $\mu$ multiplicities evolve over time:

$$
\mu_b(t+1) = \mu_{f^{-1}_t(b)}(t)
\tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$

I don't understand how he can use the inverse function $f^{-1}_t$ generically for any $b$ when each function $f_t$ is defined for one and only one $b$. Let me take a concrete example so you see what I mean.

### Example

#### Time t=0

Say that M=2 and N=2, and that the initial state of the network is this:

- N1: (0,1)
- N2: (1,1)

The multiset of multiplicities ${\mu_0(0),\mu1(0),\mu_2(0),\mu_3(0)}$ is this:

- {0,1,0,1}

#### Computation

Let's define $f_0$ as a function that takes (1,0) and outputs (0,0):

$$
f_0((0,1))=(0,0)
$$

It follows that its inverse is:

$$
f^{-1}_0((0,0))=(0,1)
$$

Equivalently, we can define these using the succinct form $b(t)$:

$$
f_0(1)=0\\
f^{-1}_0(0)=1
$$

#### Time t=1

By applying the computation $f_0$ onto the NM-bit network, we get this new network at time t=1:

- N1: (0,0)
- N2: (1,1)

And the multiset of multiplicities ${\mu_0(1),\mu1(1),\mu_2(1),\mu_3(1)}$ is this:

- {1,0,0,1}

In English:

- $\mu_0$ went from 0 to 1 (because now there's one sub-network in the state (0,0))
- $\mu_1$ went from 1 to 0 (because there's no sub-network in the state (1,0) anymore)
- $\mu_2$ and $\mu_3$ remained the same

### Question

I can see why equation $\eqref{eq2}$ holds for $\mu_0$:

$$
\mu_0(1)=\mu_{f^{-1}_0(0)}(0)
$$

We know what's the output of $f^{-1}_0(0)$, so let's substitute it:

$$
\mu_0(1)=\mu_1(0)
$$

Checks out, since we know that the multiplicity of the 0 state is time t=1 is 1 and that the multiplicity of state 1 at time t=0 is also 1.

But I cannot for the life of me understand how equation $\eqref{eq2}$ holds for $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$ and $\mu_3$, or to put it otherwise, I don't understand how it can be an equation of motion for the entire network. The inverse of the function $f_0$ is simply not defined when the input $b$ is 1, 2 or 3 - it's only defined when the input $b$ is 0. So I can't understand how $\eqref{eq2}$ can be considered an equation of motion for all multiplicities.

If we were to define $f_0$ for when $b$ is 0:

$$
f_0(0)=0
$$

We could no longer use its inverse, since $f_0$ would not be bijective anymore (inputs 0 and 1 would both lead to the same output 0).

I expected the equation of motion for the multiplicities to be some sort of piecewise function, such that each multiplicity of a given state that is left untouched by the computation is simply equal to the multiplicity of the state thereof at the previous time.

What am I missing?

Comment: TL;DR. Have you taken into account that *all* quantum systems ("gates") evolve *always* in a reversible manner ? I would therefore think that $f^{-1}_t$ should be defined for all $b$.

Comment: @KurtG. No I haven't but I guess you're getting at an answer to my question. Deutsch is talking about classical systems in the prelude though.

Comment: "classical ***reversible***" to be precise . See Deutsch p. 3.

Answer (score 1):

The paper states that

> each $f_t$ is some invertible function from $Z_{2^N}$ to itself, which characterizes the action of all the gates through which the bits pass during the $(t+1)$th computational step

So the only functions that are allowed are those that have an inverse for all of the possible values of the bits in the network. So if you define a function that doesn't have an inverse over all those values it doesn't represent an allowed evolution of a multiset.